# Write code to create table with arrow like below by css and html?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create table complex arrow-like shape with CSS like this image:

[image]

This is the current code:

```
<style>
.border-dark {
    border-color: #212529 !important;
}
.table-gray {
    background: rgb(97, 97, 97);
    color: white;
}

.table-rowspan {
    background-color:rgb(97, 97, 97) !important;
    color: white;
}
table, th, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table th:nth-child(1) {
    width: 70px;
    min-width: 70px;

}
table th:nth-child(2) {
    width: 60px;
    min-width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
}
</style>
```

```
<table class="table-bordered border-dark">
   <tr class="table-rowspan border-dark">
       <th rowspan="10" class="table-rowspan border-dark"></th>
       <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td>
   </tr>
   .....
   <tr>
      <td>9</td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

and the current result:

[image]

Please help me draw up and down arrows with any letter in the first column.
Thank you so much

Comment: Hav you investigated clip-path for the arrow shape and radial or linear gradient for the black to white part?

Comment: Usually, you would post attempted solutions to this problem. What you tried so far? May I recommend an image as a background or a `svg`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of treating the arrow section as the first column of the table, why don't you use a separate `div` for the arrow part with `position: absolute;`, `top: 0;` `left: -100%;`, and `height: 100%;`?
Ofcourse the main table `div` would be `position: relative;` and the arrow div would be its child.

This arrow `div` would further have 5 `spans`, each for the elements: alphabet on top, top pointing arrow, centre text, down pointing arrow, alphabet at the bottom.

Arrow div = `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`

Use a png for top/bottom arrow and flip if vertically for the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a quick `.svg` file for the arrows you want.
I would recommend using this as a background image for the side area and add text on top of that.

The file was software-generated so its hard to read, but it is small enough to give it a shot.
I hope you will find this at least a bit helpful.

The logic is this:

1. Create a closed path for the arrows
2. Add a radial gradient on that shape with the desired colors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 175 800" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2;">
    <path d="M87.258,48l-52.258,152.277l30.112,0l-0,399.294l-30.112,-0l52.258,152.429l51.742,-152.429l-29.705,-0l-0,-399.294l29.705,0l-51.742,-152.277Z" style="fill:url(#_Radial1);"/>
    <defs>
    <radialGradient id="_Radial1" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(-0.257918,-199.723,1351.97,-1.7459,87.2579,400)">
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#585858;stop-opacity:1"/>
    <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#d5d5d5;stop-opacity:1"/></radialGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the arrow appears to be for decorative purposes there is no need to put it into the main HTML.

This snippet draws it with a polygon which clips a path on a before pseudo element on the first th element. This has a background which goes from light gray to transparent in the middle and back to light gray.

An after pseudo element puts in some text - but more is needed here in terms of positioning as it appears the text required would be in a vertical script (?).

The black splodge effect is made with a radial gradient on the th element.

```css
.border-dark {
  border-color: #212529 !important;
}

.table-gray {
  background: rgb(97, 97, 97);
  color: white;
}

.table-rowspan {
  background-color: rgb(97, 97, 97) !important;
  color: white;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 70px;
  min-width: 70px;
}

table th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
}

th:first-child {
  position: relative;
  backgroound-image: radial-gradient(black, white);
  background-position: center center;
}

th:first-child::before {
  content: '';
  width: 70%;
  height: 90%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#eeeeee, transparent, #eeeeee);
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  --x: 30%;
  --y: 15%;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% var(--y), calc(100% - var(--x)) var(--y), calc(100% - var(--x)) calc(100% - var(--y)), 100% calc(100% - var(--y)), 50% 100%, 0% calc(100% - var(--y)), var(--x) calc(100% - var(--y)), var(--x) var(--y), 0 var(--y));
}

th:first-child::after {
  content: 'A';
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* work needed on exact positioning and requirement for text eg. vertical?? */
}
```

```html
<table class="table-bordered border-dark">
  <tr class="table-rowspan border-dark">
    <th rowspan="10" class="table-rowspan border-dark"></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Note: CSS variables, --x and --y, are used to define the arrow head. Change these if you want a more (or a less) pointy one. And change the width of the before element if you would like it fatter (or thinner). %s are used so it should be responsive if you go down that route.